# how to add inner buffer of thes polygons

Tags: buffer, qgis

i do a buffer zone around a the polygons with a specific distance.
Now i want to do the same processing but this once with inside the polygone (inner polygon) with distance of 3 meters like this pictures:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XuOw.png)

Comment: Hey, Welcome to SO! I think this question is more appropriate on [GIS (Geographic Information Systems) Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) since it's more relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try - distance for inside buffer on buffer screen. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH5py.png)

Comment: i tried with the same steps but the output buffer don't show any geometry

Comment: i think your scale so big. try same procces lower scale.

Comment: possible, hwo any idea why the buffer give the same layer with any change knowing that i change value of buffer with small and big value;